# js variables in drupal 7 form

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I have a jquery slider which collects users' values into js variables and I am able to store these values as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var amount=$('#slider_v').slider('value');

 </script>
```

Now what I want is that if a user clicks a button, they should be directed to a user/register (drupal's profile form) which will have an additional field called amount. The value from the previous page will automatically pre-fill that text-field

Any help, I am new to this, sorry